# What are all these attributes in mtTkinter.py?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to understand the mtTkinter.py to make Tkinter thread-safe.
The mtTkinter module can be found in [This Location](https://github.com/wimhendrickx/Flocking/blob/master/mtTkinter.py).

There are so many factors that I don't understand. For example

1. What is the flow of the whole module & how the whole module is working ?
2. What is **_Tk__init__** ?
3. Why it is not running properly.

*It will be nice if someone explains to me the flow and the meaning of these things*

**I know the basic of how to create a thread-safe Tkinter call**
For example I completely understand [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82965-threads-tkinter-and-asynchronous-io/) and how it is working

When I run this I get this box below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question #3 cannot be answered unless you give us more details about the precise problem you're having and what you've tried. (Ask a new question for that.) That said, I *think* I can answer your first and second questions.

1. The mtTkinter module *replaces* the Tkinter module in memory, meaning that any Tkinter functions you call after importing mtTkinter will be replaced with the versions in mtTkinter, thus providing you benefits like thread safety with very little effort.
2. `_Tk__init__` is the mtTkinter function that corresponds to `Tkinter.__init__` and replaces it, so that whatever you do with Tkinter functions and objects is done with mtTkinter functions and objects instead.

As for the image, I'm fairly sure that's what you get when you run mtTkinter itself. I think that if you `import mtTkinter as Tkinter`, you won't see that pop-up dialog.